# 6.5840 lab1，run in goland，cannot load plugin wc.so, in ubuntu22.04

Tags: ide, goland

when i run in terminal

```
go build -buildmode=plugin ../mrapps/wc.go
go run mrsequential.go wc.so pg*.txt
```

the program runs normally

when i run it in goLand

```
GOROOT=/usr/lib/go-1.18 #gosetup
GOPATH= #gosetup
/usr/lib/go-1.18/bin/go build -o /home/maikle/.cache/JetBrains/GoLand2023.3/tmp/GoLand/___go_build_6_5840_main /home/maikle/Downloads/lab/6.5840/src/main/mrsequential.go #gosetup
/home/maikle/.cache/JetBrains/GoLand2023.3/tmp/GoLand/___go_build_6_5840_main /home/maikle/Downloads/lab/6.5840/src/main/wc.so pg*.txt -buildmode=plugin -gcflags=all=-N -l ../mrapps/wc.go
2024/01/14 20:49:57 cannot load plugin /home/maikle/Downloads/lab/6.5840/src/main/wc.so

Process finished with the exit code 1
```

this is my config in goLand

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AVoQ.png)

i try it in google, but it dosen't work

Comment: Does it work if you specify an absolute path instead `../mrapps/wc.go`?